# Get animation state from Scaffold drawers

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using the drawers provided by the `Scaffold` widget and I was wondering, is there a way to access the animation state (or the `DrawerController` more specificly) from the scaffold?

If no, is there a way to use `Drawers` outside of `Scaffold` ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

i think your question means that can u open and close the drawer from outside the ScaffoldClass
if its 
then the answer is yes u can by 
first Access the ScaffoldState class and use openDrawer() method

so its gonna be like this

```
Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
```

and to close it use

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Comment: I not only want to open and close but get the actual animation value (from 0.0 to 1.0)

Comment: sorry i dont know how to get it :(